# Is transparent huge pages not a feature in Rhel 7 x64 OELS?

Tags: oracle, rhel7

I am trying to disable Transparent Huge pages as part of the installation of Oracle in a VM running Rhel7 OELS.  As far as I now, Transparent huge pages is a feature enable by default starting from rhel and centOS 7. But, I don't seem to have this feature at all. Is this normal??

Answer (score 0):

Trasparent huge page are enabled by default since RHEL 6.

To disable at boot time in grub.conf

```
transparent_hugepage=never
```

To disable at runtime

```
# echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/redhat_transparent_hugepage/enabled
# echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/redhat_transparent_hugepage/defrag
```

If HugePages_Total = 0 THP is disabled.

```
# grep -i HugePages_Total /proc/meminfo 
HugePages_Total:       0
```

Comment: I believe the above may be a bit misleading. From a server where transparent huge pages have been turned off, but where huge pages are explicitly used by an application:

$ grep -i HugePages /proc/meminfo 

AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:   242500
HugePages_Free:    20794
HugePages_Rsvd:    15624
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB

In other words: Here, HugePages_Total != 0, but THP is disabled (using the kernel argument in grub, as you wrote).

I have heard that in OEL, THP is turned off by default; so here's a difference betwen RHEL and OEL.